# Android, is it possible to change UID of my application programmatically

Tags: android

I'm trying to build an application to lock-down specific applications and services.
Ive got a list of the packages installed on the android device and I know how to disable them but when I try I get a permission denied error about the uid is different.

Is there a way to make android think I'm the user that is trying to disable the the package or to change the uid of the application I'm running as to that of the package.

I know I can get the uid of the package I'm trying to disable using the ApplicationInfo.

The way I'm disabling the packages is:

```
pm.setApplicationEnabledSetting(packageName, 
            PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED_USER, 
            PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
```

Comment: haha, ok.

Is there anyway i can disable other downloaded and system applications using the packageinfo or applicationinfo?

Comment: No, that's not possible either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way to make android think I'm the user that is trying to disable the the package or to change the uid of the application I'm running as to that of the package.

Fortunately, no, for obvious security reasons.

> Is there anyway i can disable other downloaded and system applications using the packageinfo or applicationinfo?

Fortunately, no, for obvious security reasons.

You may have additional options on rooted devices, and certainly with custom firmware.